# Can I get the method local variables through a stack trace in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get a detailed log about my stack trace. I can get a StackFrame and then the method and then get all the parameters of that method. Just as the following code:

```
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
            StackFrame[] sfs = st.GetFrames();
            foreach (StackFrame sf in sfs)
            {
                MethodBase method = sf.GetMethod();
                ParameterInfo[] pis = method.GetParameters();
                foreach (ParameterInfo pi in pis)
                {
                      ....
                }
                Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
            }
```

But how could I get the **local variables** infomation within a method?

Could someone shed some light on me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [LocalVariableInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo.aspx).

**Example fom MSDN**
        // Get method body information.

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(Example).GetMethod("MethodBodyExample");
MethodBody mb = mi.GetMethodBody();
Console.WriteLine("\r\nMethod: {0}", mi);

// Display the general information included in the 
// MethodBody object.
Console.WriteLine("    Local variables are initialized: {0}", 
    mb.InitLocals);

foreach (LocalVariableInfo lvi in mb.LocalVariables)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Local variable: {0}", lvi);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Filip. Just a further question, could I get the name/type/value of the local variables?

Comment: @smwikipedia: no, you can't :) at least not in managed code. If you were to use the unmanaged profiling APIs, it could work, but it's not an easy piece of work.

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense to get the value of the local variable since you are inspeciting it out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, Filip. I just want to log and inspect the call stack info like a debugger does.