# Distinguish between the type used to reference an object and the type of its backing store

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
using System;

interface IAnimal
{
}

class Cat: IAnimal
{
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAnimal cat = new Cat();

        // Console.WriteLine(cat.GetType());
           // This would only give me the type of 
           // the backing store, i.e. Cat. Is there a 
           // way I can get to know that the identifier 
           // cat was declared as IAnimal?

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Thanks to Dan Bryant for the reminder.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TypeInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IAnimal myCat = new Cat();
            ReflectOnType();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void ReflectOnType()
        {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
                GetType("TypeInfo.Program").
                GetMethod("Main", 
                BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.Public).
                GetMethodBody().LocalVariables.
                ToList().
                ForEach( l => Console.WriteLine(l.LocalType));
        }
    }

    interface IAnimal { }
    class Cat : IAnimal { }
}
```

Comment: It's possible, but you have reflect on the Method itself; LocalVariableInfo has a LocalType you can use.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696691/can-i-get-the-method-local-variables-through-a-stack-trace-in-c

Comment: Why would you want to do this when the type is statically available already?

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Damn! Damn! Damn! I use LocalVariableInfo and LocalType all the time. What's wrong with me? And I have used it in a similar scenario earlier. Damn! Why did I ask this question?

Thanks a million for the reminder.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? If I have IAnimal animal = new Cat(); Object sth = animal; then you expect IAnimal or Object? I have a gut feeling that whatever you want to achieve should be done in a different way.

Comment: @Grzenio: In your scenario, the backing store would be Cat and not IAnimal, and so I would still expect the object used to dereference and not the backing store. That is to say, I'd expect to see System.object. And the LocalType on LocalVariableInfo would give me just that. Thanks again, Dan Bryant.

Comment: Oh Noez! Wait!!!! LocalType, I suspect, would still dish out the type of the backing store. Let me check this.

Comment: What is a Backing Store? Google didn't provide much help as all of its results seemed to be something different. What's going on here? Why declare a new IAnimal object as Cat instead of simply declaring a Cat object in the first place?

I'm not criticizing, rather I'm trying to grasp a concept that is foreign to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic type inference:

```
using System;

internal interface IAnimal
{
}

internal class Cat : IAnimal
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cat = new Cat();
        Console.WriteLine(cat.GetType()); // Cat
        Console.WriteLine(GetStaticType(cat)); // Cat

        IAnimal animal = cat;
        Console.WriteLine(GetStaticType(animal)); // IAnimal
    }

    static Type GetStaticType<T>(T _)
    {
        return typeof (T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per suggestion above, I'm posting this as an answer.  See the comments above for further context.

---

You indicated that you're still seeing the 'backing store' with LocalVariableInfo.  What this suggests to me is that the declaration is purely in the source and not actually encoded in the method at all. The fact that you chose to use an interface as the 'declared' type is irrelevant, as the compiler chose to use the more specific type for the local variable slot. Try running ILdasm on your DLL output and you can see if this is true. If it is, your only option is to actually look at the source code, since the information literally doesn't exist in the compiled version.

Comment: I stand corrected. I wasn't. While I'd written the code to use LocalVariableInfo.LocalType, I was, err, not even calling the code. My calling code still had Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType()).