# Languages supporting complete reflection

Tags: reflection, programming-languages

Only recently, I discovered that both Java and C# do not support reflection of local variables. For example, you cannot retrieve the names of local variables at runtime.

Although clearly this is an optimisation that makes sense, I'm curious as to whether any current languages support full and complete reflection of all declarations and constructs.

**EDIT:** I will qualify my "names of local variables" example a bit further.
In C#, you can output the names of parameters to methods using reflection:

```
foreach(ParameterInfo pi in typeof(AClass).GetMethods()[0].GetParameters())
    Trace.WriteLine(pi.Name);
```

You don't need to know the names of the parameters (or even of the method) - it's all contained in the reflection information. In a fully-reflective language, you would be able to do:

```
foreach(LocalVariableInfo lvi in typeof(AClass).GetMethods()[0].GetLocals())
    Trace.WriteLine(lvi.Name);
```

The applications may be limited (many applications of reflection are), but nevertheless, I would expect a reflection-complete language to support such a construct.

**EDIT**: Since two people have now effectively said "there's no point in reflecting local variable names", here's a basic example of why it's useful:

```
void someMethod()
{
    SomeObject x = SomeMethodCall();

    // do lots of stuff with x
    // sometime later...

    if (!x.StateIsValid)
       throw new SomeException(String.Format("{0} is not valid.", nameof(x));
}
```

Sure, I could just hardcode "x" in the string, but correct refactoring support makes that a big no-no. `nameof(x)` or the ability to reflect all names is a nice feature that is currently missing.

Comment: I have altered "determine the name of a local variable" to "retrieve the names of local variables", which is what your code example actually does.

Comment: Please check out my video series, Squeak from the very start: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6601A198DF14788D&feature=view_all

Answer (score 1):

Your introductory statement about the names of local variables drew my interest.

This code will actually retrieve the name of the local var inside the lambda expression:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 5;
    Expression<Func<int>> expr = (() => a);
    Console.WriteLine(expr.Compile().Invoke());

    Expression ex = expr;
    LambdaExpression lex = ex as LambdaExpression;
    MemberExpression mex = lex.Body as MemberExpression;
    Console.WriteLine(mex.Member.Name);
}
```

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696691/can-i-get-the-method-local-variables-through-a-stack-trace-in-c) mentioning [LocalVariableInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo.aspx).

Comment: It appears that I was missing the fact the local variables are part of the method body, rather than the method itself, which does make sense. And reflection of local variables is included. But LocalVariableInfo does not include the variable name which seems like an odd exception when compared with ParameterInfo. Moving on...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are languages where this is (at least kind of) possible. I would say that reflection in both Smalltalk and Python are pretty "complete" for any reasonable definition.

That said, getting the name of a local variable is pretty pointless - by definition to get the name of that variable, you must know its name. I wouldn't consider the lack of an operation to perform that exact task a lacuna in the reflection facility.

Your second example does not "determine the name of a local variable", it retrieves the name of all local variables, which is a different task. The equivalent code in Python would be:

```
for x in locals().iterkeys(): print x
```

Comment: In much the same way that you don't need to know the type of a variable to find out its type, reflection should allow you to get the name of an instance without knowing it's name. In theory.

Comment: @adelphus: No, you are confused. The name is how you refer to the variable, so in a language with typed variables (as distinct from typed values), you would still need the name of the variable to query its type. This is different from having a value, and being able to query the runtime system for a list of variables that currently refer to that value.

Answer (score 0):

eh, in order to access a local var you have to be within the stackframe/context/whatever where the local var is valid. Since it is only valid at that point in time, does it matter if it is called 't1' or 'myLittlePony'?

Comment: Actual variable naming does matter, though is a bit out of scope for my question. If someone names all their variables t1, t2, t3, t4.. then I'm sure you wouldn't be happy! Likewise if they named their variable myLittlePony when it had nothing to do with ponies!!!

Comment: The real point I was trying to make was that reflection is incomplete in C# and Java for no apparent reason. And hence, whether any other languages were fully reflective, regardless of the real-world applications.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6601A198DF14788D&feature=view_all  is a video series on smalltalk. There are plenty of examples of full reflection in the various videos. Most IDEs outside of Smalltalk do NOT support full reflection, even if the language does.